# Laravel Eloquent search two optional fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to search two optional tables using eloquent:

```
$users  = User::where('ProfileType', '=', 2)
                ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('BandName', 'LIKE', "%$artist%");
                    $query->or_where('Genre', 'LIKE', "%$genre%");
                })->get();
```

This works fine for return all results when a user does an empty search, but I am not sure how to adjust this for to search for bandname when that is present and vise versa.

Comment: So will the query always be: WHERE ProfileType = 2 AND (BandName = 'foo' OR Genre = 'bar')? I'm trying to figure out what search values will always be present and which ones may not always exist.

Comment: Yes, ProfileType will always be present, but BandName and Genre are both optional and can even be left blank.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Vinicius' answer here's what worked:

```
// Instantiates a Query object
$query = User::where('ProfileType', '=', '2');

// Adds a clause to the query
if ($artist = Input::get('artist')) {
    $query->where('BandName', 'LIKE', "%$artist%");
    // Temp Usernamesearch
    $query->or_where('NickName', 'LIKE', "%$artist%");
}

// Genre - switch function if artist is not empty
if ($genre = Input::get('genre')) {
    $func = ($artist) ? 'or_where' : 'where';
    $query->$func('Genre', 'LIKE', "%$genre%");
}

// Executes the query and fetches it's results
$users = $query->get();
```

Turns out that the second optional field must use or_where only if $artist is not set.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10):

Just to explain what happens on answer below:

Eloquent does a tricky thing here: When you call `User::where(...)` it returns a [Database\ Query](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Database.Query.html) object. This is basically the same thing as `DB::table('users')->where(...)`, a chainable object for constructing SQL queries.

So having:

```php
// Instantiates a Query object
$query = User::where('ProfileType', '=', '2');
$query->where(function($query) {
    // Adds a clause to the query
    if ($artist = Input::get('artist')) {
        $query->where_nested('BandName', 'LIKE', "%$artist%", 'OR');
    }
    // And another
    if ($genre = Input::get('genre')) {
        $query->where_nested('Genre', 'LIKE', "%$genre%", 'OR');
    }
});

// Executes the query and fetches it's results
$users = $query->get();
```

Comment: This answer looks good but for some reason is not finding any results.  Not sure what the problem is

Comment: Ow, I didn't realize you would like to search multiple fields with OR. Usually each field behaves as a filter. In that case, AND is the way to go. I'll edit the answer and provide some clarification.

Comment: Can this be done in one inputfield? For example a name filter that checks if the filter equals firstname OR lastname...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what youre after. Your view would have a form to search artist/genre one or the other can be set, or both, or none.

```
$users = User::where('ProfileType', '=', 2);

if (Input::has('artist')) {
    $users = $users->where('BandName', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('artist').'%');
}

if (Input::has('genre')) {
    $users = $users->where('Genre', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('genre').'%');
}

$users = $users->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = FormEntry::with('form')->where('domain_id', $id);

$query->where(function($query) use ($search, $start, $limit, $order, $dir) {                
     $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
           ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
           ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
           ->offset($start)
           ->limit($limit)
           ->orderBy($order, $dir);
      });

$entries = $query->get();
$totalFiltered = $query->count();
```