# Laravel Eloquent query with optional parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to learn whether or not there is a simple way to pass a variable number of parameters to a query in Eloquent, hopefully using an `array`.

From what I can find, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this without looping through the `Input` to see what was set in the request.

Examples here: [Laravel Eloquent search two optional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167770/laravel-eloquent-search-two-optional-fields)

This would work, but feels non-Laravel to me in its complexity/inelegance.

Here is where I am, and this may not be possible, just hoping someone else has solved a similar issue:

```
$where = array("user_id" => 123, "status" => 0, "something else" => "some value");

        $orders = Order::where($where)->get()->toArray();
        return Response::json(array(
                'orders' => $orders
                ),
            200
        );
```

That returns an error of course `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Order::where actually returns an instance of query builder, so this is probably easier than you thought.  If you just want to grab that instance of query builder and "build" your query one where() at a time you can get it like this:

```
$qb = (new Order)->newQuery();
foreach ($searchParams as $k => $v) {
    $qb->where($k, $v);
}
return $qb->get(); // <-- fetch your results
```

If you ever want to see what query builder is doing you can also execute that get() and shortly after:

```
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

That will show you what the resulting query looks like; this can be very useful when playing with Eloquent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see this is possible, I was hoping to just do it in one shot, by passing an `array`. But this is also informative in that I didn't know you can do the `(new Order)` part. Also a really great band.

Comment: I can confirm this DOES work. If no one else has a magical answer in a bit, I will mark this one.

Comment: Haha.  I just do it that way because Model->newQuery() gets a new query builder for the model's table...it's easy to read and I don't believe there is a static equivalent.  Either way, Builder uses the "builder pattern" -- the keyword being builder.  The keyword for "factory" is like you said "one-shot."  I don't know of a query factory in Laravel but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: That's priceless info. You win. Well, you were were not really getting much competition. the `dd` thing I was also unaware of. The more I try to move away from PHP the more I love Laravel. That guy really did something good.

Comment: Where did you learn about the `(new Model)->newQuery()`? I don't see anything like that in the docs and whenever I ask a Laravel question, I get something like that I have not seen before.

Comment: I just randomly tried that (new Thing)->etc() one day and it worked.  I'm not sure it's supported in earlier versions of PHP.  It's a weird thing to do, really, because why would you ever not want a reference to an instance?  Rare case for sure.  I'm not sure why newQuery() wasn't a static method but I'm sure there's a reason and I would probably start by reading Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model's __callStatic().  You can also just do $o = new Order; $qb = $o->newQuery();

Comment: For future users: I prefer this: `
  $obj = new Order; 
  $orders = $obj->newQuery();` Thanks @Plywood for your insight.

Comment: Just an addition to @Plywood's answer - you can also use `->toSql()` in order to view what the query actually looks like in SQL. So, f.e. if you have it as `$qb->where($k, $v)->get()`, then you would use `$qb->where($k, $v)->toSql()` in order to view the SQL query that's gonna be executed in fact. Correct me if I went off into another direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Method 1:**

If you have one optional search parameter received in input

```
$orders = Order::select('order_id','order_value',...other columns);

if($request->has(user_id)) {
   $orders->where('orders.user_id','=',$request->user_id);
}

//considering something_else as a substring that needs to be searched in orders table
if($request->has('something_else')) {
    $orders->where('orders.column_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->something_else.'%');
}

$orders->paginate(10);
```

**Method 2:**

If you have multiple optional parameters in input

```
$orders = Order::select('columns');
foreach($input_parameters as $key => $value) {
    //this will return results for column_name=value
    $orders->where($key, $value);//key should be same as the column_name

    //if you need to make some comparison
    $orders->where($key, '>=', $value);//key should be same as the column_name
}
return $orders->paginate(15);
```