# Simplify Eloquent Laravel with multiple filters and pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, object, eloquent

My question is about simplifying multiple Eloquent queries that work with Laravel pagination.

I am building a Laravel website, on this website people can share certain recipes.

I have multiple variables that members can search, filter and look trough.
So members can post recipes and add:
 - Type
 - Duration
 - Country
 - Platform

The idea is that there is a page with all the recipes, but there are also pages where only recipes for 1, 2 or more filters are applied. E.g. cold 5 minute recipes or German Warm Long recipes.

Im using Laravel 5.7 and now im building all kind of queries with different where statements. Like this:

```
 public static function getRecipesMixFilter($cid, $pid, $tid, $did)
{
    $recipes = self::with(['member', 'platform', 'member.platform', 'member.duration', 'member.type'])->whereActive(1)->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($cid, $pid, $tid, $did) {
            $query->where('country_id', '=', $cid)
            ->where('platform_id', '=', $pid)
            ->where('type_id', '=', $tid)
            ->where('duration_id', '=', $did);
    })->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(24);

    return $recipes;
}
```

But what is the easy way to do this? Now I have 15 different queries, where I feel it could be 1. So that the **->where('platform_id', '=', 1)** etc. are optional.

When I try to filter on each object so the first Platform, then Type and so on, I cant apply the pagination.

Is there a way to simplify this? And can I use Ajax filters with Laravel pagination?

Comment: You're returning `$username`, but the variable is not defined anywhere in the method

Comment: I just edited it, so that it should work & without $username.

Comment: You could try making all the parameters optional, then only adding each one to the filter if it's been set, like `if ($cid) $query->where('country_id', '=', $cid);`, etc.

Comment: But its a joined query, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072212/laravel-eloquent-query-with-optional-parameters, but that doesnt seem to do the trick

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think you should post answer on how to use optional params. That would solve his problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make them optional by doing this:

```
public static function getRecipesMixFilter($cid = null, $pid = null, $tid = null, $did = null)
{
    $recipes = self::with(['member', 'platform', 'member.platform', 'member.duration', 'member.type'])
        ->whereActive(1)
        ->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($cid, $pid, $tid, $did) {
            if ($cid) {
                $query->where('country_id', '=', $cid)
            }
            if ($pid) {
                $query->where('platform_id', '=', $pid)
            }
            if ($tid) {
                $query->where('type_id', '=', $tid)
            }
            if ($did) {
                $query->where('duration_id', '=', $did)
            }
        })->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(24);

    return $recipes;
}
```